# How to determine where to zoom and pan on an image in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, gesture

When developing with SwiftUI, I am using an Image() and would like to be able to not only zoom in on it, which I am currently doing, but would like to zoom in on different areas of it and to pan across to different areas.  It seems I can only zoom in on it from one area as the origin of the zoom (center) but would like to zoom from where on the image the gesture started from to so speak.  Here is the code so far:

```
ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]) {
                Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: self.document.image)!)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .padding()
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .scaleEffect(self.scale, anchor: .center)
                .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height, alignment: .center)
                .gesture(MagnificationGesture()
                    .onChanged { val in
                        let delta = (val / self.lastScale)
                        self.lastScale = val
                        self.scale = (self.scale * delta)
                    }
                    .onEnded { val in
                        self.lastScale = 1.0
                    }
                )
                .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
                    self.scale = 1.0
                    self.lastScale = 1.0
                }
            }
            .frame(width: geo.size.width - 50, height: geo.size.height - 90, alignment: .center)
            .clipped()
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

UPDATED Code seems to do the trick for me:

```
Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: self.document.image)!)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .padding()
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .scaleEffect(self.finalAmount + self.currentAmount)
                .offset(x: self.currentPosition.width, y: self.currentPosition.height)
                .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height, alignment: .center)
                .clipped()
                .scaleEffect(1.15)
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$isSheetActive) {
                    ShareSheet(activityItems: [self.MakeImageFileToShare(uiimage: UIImage(data: self.document.image)!)])
                }
                .gesture(MagnificationGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                         if self.finalAmount + value - 1 >= 1 {
                                  self.currentAmount = value - 1
                              }
                          }
                          .onEnded { amount in
                              self.finalAmount += self.currentAmount
                          self.currentAmount = 0
                    }
                .simultaneously(with: DragGesture()
                    .onChanged({ value in
                        self.currentPosition = CGSize(width: value.translation.width + self.newPosition.width, height: value.translation.height + self.newPosition.height)
                    })
                    .onEnded ({ value in
                        self.currentPosition = CGSize(width: value.translation.width + self.newPosition.width, height: value.translation.height + self.newPosition.height)
                        self.newPosition = self.currentPosition
                })))
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: simme - I didn't but decided to use the .offset modifier and also a combo of the DragGesture and the MagnificationGesture which seem to get what I was looking to do.  See updated code above in original post.

Comment: @GoldenRetriever - but the scaling is still centred around the middle of the view, right? Not centred on the mid-point between the two finger touches?

Comment: @poltavets - yeah, you're absolutely correct.  That was the closest I had come at the time but as you see, it wasn't exactly what I was looking for unfortunately.